# Replace ${abc} in text file using Perl, but not \${abc}

Tags: regex, perl

The title sort of says it all. I have a text file (NOT a perl file), which contains any number of placeholders over many lines and possibly several on the same line. Here's an example:

> Hello ${first} ${last}, please visit us at http://${host}${context}
>   and mind the \${variables}.

I need to replace everything that looks like `${...}` but not what looks like `\${...}`. So this example needs to convert to:

> Hello John Doe, please visit us at http://example.com/foobar
>   and mind the \${variables}.

My expression currently looks like this:

`s/([^\\])\$\{\s*([^\}\s]+)\s*\}/$1 . _lookupVar( $2, $varMap )/ge`

where `_lookupVar` is a function that knows how to insert the right value. I have the first `[^\\]` there in order to avoid replacing `\${...}` sequences, but this means that for `${host}${context}`, only `${host}` gets replaced. And for various reasons, I can't really turn `${host}${context}` into `${host} ${context}`.

I can hack something, but I was wondering whether I'm missing some regex magic that somebody knowledgeable might like to teach me ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind assertion `(?<!\\)` rather than a negative character class `[^\\]`:

```
s/(?<!\\)\$\{\s*([^\}\s]+)\s*\}/_lookupVar($1, $varMap)/ge
```

The character class consumes the character just behind the `$` (resulting in you having to put it back with `$1`), while the negative lookbehind simply checks to see if there's a `\` there; if not, match the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

To allow cases like:

```
\\${foo}
```

You could use something like:

```
s/(?<!\\)(?:\\\\)* \K \${ \s* ([^\s}]+) \s* }/_lookupVar($1, $varMap)/gxe
```

Comment: I think you mean `(?:\\\\)`, not `(?:\\.)`